# how to insert html syntax inside of encoded code block <%#: %> or htmldecode

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, decode, encode

I have this code in aspx page:

```
<%#: !String.IsNullOrEmpty(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Legal").ToString()) ? "Legal <br>" : "" %>
<%#: !String.IsNullOrEmpty(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Register").ToString()) ? "Registered <br>" : "" %>
```

How can I decode? I am trying to replace `<br>` with `Environment.Newline` but it's not working.

Comment: these codes inside <ItemTemplate> in RadGrid

Comment: Give us more details on what you tried and how to problem appears.